# Where can I view the code behind the .net library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

For instance, in my coding I using the VB function

```
Round(1.325, 2)
```

Which produces the number 1.33. I am wondering if there is a place to view the code behind the "Round" function so that I can produce my own.

Reason for the question:

I was recently asked in an interview to produce a reverse function that does not use the .Reverse function from the .net library. I nailed it, but there are other basic functions to learn such as formatting a number to a set amount of decimal places. Being able to look at the code behind the .net library functions would aide me in this pursuit.

TIA - Thanks in advance.

James

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: or grab a decompiler.  There's a lot of free ones

Comment: There are also NET counterparts to all those legacy VB function if you dont like exactly how they work

Comment: The problem is that `Math.Round` calls "internal" implementations that are not available in the reference source.

Comment: Also remember that the point of these interview questions should not be to get the "right" answer, but to see how you work through a problem.  So regurgitating "correct" code without illustrating your thought process (or worse yet without explaining _why_ it works) may be worse than thinking through the problems and solving them on-the-fly.  99%+ of software development is writing _new_ code, not just reusing already existing code.  I'm not saying your goal is not appropriate, just to argue that you may be thinking of these questions from an incorrect point-of-view.

Comment: @DStanley You are right there. They told me I did a really good job on explaining the process needed even if I did use VB, lol.

Comment: @DStanley, it is not on referencesource, but it is on GitHub.  InternalCall is [mapped in `ecalllist.h`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L1241) and Math.Round is implemented in [`COMDouble::Round`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/classlibnative/float/floatdouble.cpp#L201).

Answer (score 5):

For the portions of the .Net Framework that are implemented in C#, it is easiest to review them using http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.  For the rest, you will need to either download a copy of the SSCLI or [browse the coreclr repository](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755) on GitHub.

There was a [free eBook published](http://www.newardassociates.com/files/SSCLI2.pdf) which tries to explain the inner workings of much of the SSCLI2, which is a slimmed down version of .Net 2.

`InternalCall` is handled by the runtime using mappings defined [in the file `ecalllist.h` in coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L1241), or in `ecall.cpp` for sscli.  For example, Math.Round is mapped as:

```
// snip
FCFuncStart(gMathFuncs)
    FCIntrinsic("Sin", COMDouble::Sin, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Sin)
    FCIntrinsic("Cos", COMDouble::Cos, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Cos)
    FCIntrinsic("Sqrt", COMDouble::Sqrt, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Sqrt)
    FCIntrinsic("Round", COMDouble::Round, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Round)
// snip
```

If we then look at the class `COMDouble`, whose implementation we can [find in `comfloat.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/classlibnative/float/floatdouble.cpp#L201), we see the code behind `Math.Round`:

```
/*====================================Round=====================================
**
==============================================================================*/
FCIMPL1_V(double, COMDouble::Round, double x)
    FCALL_CONTRACT;

    // If the number has no fractional part do nothing
    // This shortcut is necessary to workaround precision loss in borderline cases on some platforms
    if (x == (double)((INT64)x)) {
        return x;
    }

    // We had a number that was equally close to 2 integers.
    // We need to return the even one.

    double tempVal = (x + 0.5);
    double flrTempVal = floor(tempVal);

    if ((flrTempVal == tempVal) && (fmod(tempVal, 2.0) != 0)) {
        flrTempVal -= 1.0;
    }

    return _copysign(flrTempVal, x);
FCIMPLEND
```

Comment: Thanks @Mitch! You guys rock!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you can download and browse the source code of the .NET Framework at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/.

Note that some managed methods are just wrappers for native methods. You can find the implementation of some of these which are part of .NET Core at GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755